# How to list all repositories (cross organization) using Azure DevOps API

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

Is there a way to list every repository from an ADO instance using the API?
I see it is possible to [list the repository of a specific Project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/repositories/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP) but that would result in many API calls (1 per project for each organization). Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no other way. What you can do to improve is call first for [projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/projects/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP)

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/projects?api-version=6.0
```

and use response to iterate and get all repositories.